# What color scheme to set in the Git PowerShell window

Tags: git, powershell, colors

Please refer to the screenshots. The Git PowerShell

For some reason when I set background color to `WHITE` and the foreground colors to `BLACK` it didn't perform it properly. It looks like the `PowerShell/Terminal` does not perform by properly setting the font color.

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

```
C:\Users\Igor\OneDrive\Documents\dbhandler_app [master ↑2 +1 ~1 -0 !]> git config -l | grep color
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
```

Comment: That certainly looks like black (text) on white (background) to me. As for the [tag:git] tag, you can choose which colors Git uses; the defaults are aimed for use with either black-on-white (as you've set) or white-on-black, but it looks like your particular terminal's yellow is too bright against your white background to read well.

Comment: @torek, I need to fix the the output of `git status` - I don't care about anything else. Because this one is completely unreadable...

Comment: Yes, your `git status` output should have red and green, like your `git diff`. For some reason you're getting white-on-white. Did you configure any of the Git color variables? (`git config -l | grep color` in sh/bash will find any such settings.)

Comment: @torek, see an OP edit.

Comment: Hm, OK, those look fine (they're the modern defaults, except for `color.interactive=true`). You can temporarily set `color.status=false` or run `git -c color.status=false status` while you fix things. The odd thing to me is that the diff text shows up fine. The default coloring is to emit ESC [ 31 m for red and ESC [ 32 m for green; the terminal window interpreter is supposed to use these two to switch to "red foreground" and "green foreground" respectively. (Git will cancel the color with ESC [ m. These are ANSI standard color escapes dating to the 1990s.)

Comment: @torek,, what does this command do? And how will I fix it? As you can see the color should be black.

Comment: Which command? The `-c` *option* to `git` sets a configuration setting for the duration of one command, so `git -c color.status=false status` is like `git config color.status false; git status` except that the two-command variant sets that setting permanently (in the local config, not in your per-user `--global` one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, yesterday I updated my Git client and the wizard didn't have an option to select `PowerShell`.

So I chose `Bash` and there is no color issues anymore.

Thx for reading and sorry for time waste.